# in "its battery pack restricted cargo space", is the battery or cargo space limited?

Tags: ambiguity

Please help me with this one especially because it's stressing me out big time.

The text goes: *"The vehicle was the second mass-produced hybrid on the American market, after the two seat Honda Insight. While the larger Prius could seat five, **its battery pack restricted cargo space**".*

The task is to select appropriate words for a summary:

*The innovated Prius has considerably higher running velocity and longer distances. Still, the load capacity of current Prius version was limited in its....*

*A. battery*

*B. cargo space*

The provided solution is A. I personally think it should be B.

It's really confusing and hard to understand.

Your opinion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is B "Cargo space", largely for the reasons you give.

The cargo space is limited *by* the battery pack.

The Prius is limited *in* its cargo space.

Note that since we are speaking of the "current Prius", the verb should be in the present tense  "*is* limited in its cargo space". Moreover "innovated" seems like a odd word.  The verb isn't normally transative, so a passive participle is wrong.  Perhaps "innovative" would be better.

Answer (score 0):

The answer suggested "battery", probably because the battery *limits* the cargo space, not the cargo space limiting the battery pack. It may seem confusing, but when you say "its battery pack restricted cargo space", it means the battery pack is large enough so it restricts the cargo space, not *limiting* the cargo space.

Although limit and restrict are synonyms, there is a slight difference that may cause the answer sheet to choose "battery". Think of it like this

> The battery cannot be any larger due to it *restricting* the cargo space

> The battery cannot be any larger due to the *restricted* cargo space

Plus, you cannot really say the below

> Still, the load capacity of current Prius version was limited in its cargo space

As, load capacity and cargo space are the same thing in this context, so:

> Still, the load capacity of current Prius version was limited in its battery

Means the load capacity is limited *because* of the battery pack

Comment: In your first example, it should really  be "due to its restricting the cargo space" (subject of a gerund takes the possessive case).

Answer (score 0):

When I originally read the sentence, I thought that "battery-pack-restricted" was being used as a compound adjective and was missing the dashes (battery-pack-restricted cargo space). I had to reread it to understand the meaning.

However, I believe the sentence is incorrect, which contributes to the confusion. "Cargo space" is something specific and requires an article. The correct sentence is:

> While the larger Prius could seat five, its battery pack restricted **the** cargo space.

(**its** cargo space also works)